# Why do Singapore leaders earn so much more compared to others?

Tags: international, public-sector-compensation, singapore

> German Bundestag members earn the equivalent of $186,859 annually,
> while members of Italy’s Camera dei deputati take home $184,095 per
> year.
>
> **When it comes to world leaders, Singapore still comes out on top,
> paying their prime minister the equivalent of $2,217,188.82 in 2023.**
>
> The $543,562 Canadian earned by the U.S. president came second,
> followed by the Australian PM’s $520,332 salary.
>
> Canada’s prime minister ranked sixth, between the $420,527 earned by
> Austria’s chancellor, and the $383,909 salary of the prime minister of
> New Zealand.
>
> The Leger poll found that just 14 per cent were in favour of the pay
> rise, with just two per cent expressing strong support.

https://nationalpost.com/news/on-april-1-canadian-mps-will-earn-worlds-second-highest-salary-for-elected-officials

I was looking at the statistics and found out that they won more than 2 million dollars in salary. A lot more than people from the U.S. or Canada who are among the highest paid in the world. Is there a reason for that huge gap? Did the government of Singapore make any official statement about this and how do they justify it?

Comment: Note that the comparison in your quote are comparing apples to oranges. There are a few hundred German members of the Bundestag and Italian Camera dei deputati (both analogous to member of parliament) whereas all the other ones look at the single top head of goverment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is easily Googled for.

> Just to remind everyone, political appointment holders in Singapore are the most highly paid in the world. The government has justified their salaries by saying they’re necessary to attract the country’s top talent and prevent the kind of corruption that is rife in other Southeast Asian countries.

[Source](https://coconuts.co/singapore/features/million-dollar-question-do-singapores-ministers-deserve-a-raise/)